# Load search results into a div

Tags: search

Is there anyway to load the search results into a div in wordpress? I am currently searching a custom post type only and am searching from a small box that pops up in a fancybox. is there anyway to just have the search results load into that same box? iframe maybe?

Comment: would I just modify my custom search-xx.php template or could I use jQuery .submit() .. ??

Comment: @jeffery I think both of thouse are options. It also depends on the fancybox if it allows iframes you may just be able to "refresh" the fancybox content with the results.

Answer (score 1):

If your form is already loaded inside fancybox you can updated it using ajax and simply assign the results to that fancybox instance `$.fancybox(ajaxdata);`

To get a better understanding take a look at example 5 at [**this page**](http://fancybox.net/blog)

Hope this helps.